# Unrecognized properties in css classes in .scss with blazor web assembly

Tags: sass, blazor-webassembly

I have written the following css class in my Blazor WASM project from the standard template:

```
    .edit-field {
    input {
        border-top: none;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: none;
        outline: none;
        display: block;
    }
    span {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

This is a .scss file.

I then import it to the main css file, which is loaded to page.

It seems hard to have it broken, but I get this:
[image: Dev tools view]

If I take the properties out of the class in the same file, the issue doesn't appear and all works expectably.

I don't mean this or any other .scss file to be a css isolation style sheet.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is no blazor issue at all. It appears, css does not support nested styling originally and all my time using it, I exploited an scss feature. I installed and configured Web Compiler extension in my VS-19 and it started working as I wanted.